# Pivot Point Equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

Assume we have a platform fixed to a pivot point:

-Forgive the crude image-
[image]

We use 2 rods, either side of the pivot point, but at different distances from it.

If we were to lift ROD 1 by a certain amount, how much would ROD 2 have to lower?

What other information is needed in solving this problem?

Comment: Hi Martin and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie, Hi John, I'm actually a CS student. This simple problem just popped into my head and I've overcomplicated it so much that I'm lost.

Comment: If the rod is straight, every point along the rod moves by an amount that is proportional to the distance to the pivot (by similar triangles). That hardly qualifies as physics... it's basic geometry.